# database not created in windows phone 8 using cordova sqLite plugin

Tags: sql, sqlite, cordova, windows-phone-8

I am using html5 and cordova web sql and sqlite plugin for windows phone 8. i am using this

```
var db = WebSocket.openDatabase("test", "Test DB", 2 * 1024 * 1024);
```

but it is not creating my database. please help

Comment: i also used 
var db = window.openDatabase("test", "Test DB", 2 * 1024 * 1024);
var db = html5sql.openDatabase("test", "Test DB", 2 * 1024 * 1024);
var db = websql.openDatabase("test", "Test DB", 2 * 1024 * 1024);

Comment: Aren't you missing a parameter ? The third parameter is supposed to be a text message and not the size of the database. See: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/html5/html5_web_sql.htm

Comment: var db = openDatabase('mydb', '1.0', 'Test DB', 2 * 1024 * 1024);

i also used this but the results are same

Comment: is it returning a null for db? I tried to execute var db = openDatabase('mydb', '1.0', 'Test DB', 2 * 1024 * 1024); and it worked on chrome.

Comment: yes, it is returning null and i am running it in windows phone 8 using cordova 3.0.0

Comment: what kind of plugin do you use? have you already tried to run window.openDatabase instead of WebSocket.openDatabase?

Comment: i am using websql plugin on cordova for wp8 platform .I have already tried that one also

Answer (score 0):

Please try using [Microsoft Cordova Plugin for database](https://github.com/MSOpenTech/cordova-plugin-websql). FYI, [WebSql is not supported](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/6.0.0/cordova/storage/storage.html) on windows phone 8 and above.